# Is it possible to run the Docker container without specifying the port number

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want the dynamic port to be assigned to my docker container.
Is it possible ??

```
docker run -p 9999:9999 --network develop_cloud --name test_service --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd jcibe_supplier_collaboration/sc-ffgenerator-service-mapics:develop
```

This is the command which I am running for running the container. What changes I need to do for Running it on without specifying the port number.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports, you can just specify the container port and a host port will by dynamically assigned.  So in your case:

```
docker run -p 9999 --network develop_cloud --name test_service --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd jcibe_supplier_collaboration/sc-ffgenerator-service-mapics:develop
```

This will map port 9999 from the container to a randomly allocated port on the host.

Comment: Wanted to add that if you use the `-P` flag (capital p) all exposed ports on the container will be assigned with a random host port